# Hide unhide toolbars based on the editors open

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

In eclipse there are certain toolbars which becomes visible when I open java editor. It goes invisible when I close  the editor (only one editor was open.)

Here opening the java editor is not changing the perspective.

How to achieve this functionality in eclipse rcp application?

Comment: This might be of some help: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: thanks a lot gilber, I will look into that and get back to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Pre-3.3 this can be accomplished through a org.eclipse.ui.IEditorActionBarContributor, [defined in your editor extension with the contributorClass attribute](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_editors.html).

Since 3.3 a [core expression definition](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_expressions_definitions.html) can be used in a visiblewhen expression.

For example, a re-usable core expression for an editor can be defined as follows

```
<extension point = "org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
  <definition id="org.eclipse.ui.examples.contributions.activeEditor">    
     <with variable="activeEditorId">
        <equals value="org.eclipse.ui.examples.contributions.editor"/>
     </with>
  </definition>
</extension>
```

Then the following expression can be used to control whether a menu or toolbar is visible

```
<visibleWhen>
  <reference definitionId=""org.eclipse.ui.examples.contributions.activeEditor"/>
</visibleWhen>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at Activities and Contexts to hide/unhide contributions

http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/